# Как в название файла добавлять значение счетчика i

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("How much create a file?: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);

    for(int i = 0;i < n; i++);
    {
        FILE* file = fopen("test.txt","w");

        for(int j = 0;j < n;j++)
        {
            fprintf(file, "С is the best\n" );
        }
    }
    printf("Successfully Created");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В C нужно будет вручную привести строку к заданному виду. Допустим, всем файлам мы хотим дать название `test_N.txt`, где N — наш счетчик. Тогда наиболее предпочтительным вариантом будет использовать функцию [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

```
/* Подготавливаем строку: */
char buffer[1024];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "test_%d.txt", i);

/* Открываем файл с заданным именем: */
FILE *file = fopen(buffer, "w");
```

В примере выше размер буфера определяется как 1024. В принципе, такого размера вполне достаточно для любого значения счетчика. Однако 1024 слишком нестрогое ограничение сверху. Максимальное значение типа `int` — `INT_MAX` по стандарту равно +32767. Однако реализации в праве увеличить этот максимум. Тогда приемлемым вариантом будет в качестве максимального значения взять 2147483647, так как практически на всех машинах это и есть максимальное значение типа `int`. Тогда размер буфера будет считаться как количество цифр в 2147483647 + длина строки `"test.txt"`: 18 (+1 для нуль-терминатора).

```
char buffer[19];
```

Хотя, конечно, в вашем варианте кода будет ограничение на количество одновременно открытых файлов. Поэтому каждый файл, после работы с ним, нужно закрывать.

Answer (score 2):

Из примера вашего кода не слишком понятно, что  именно вы делаете, но динамически создавать имена файлов можно с помощью функции [snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Например, вот так:

```
....
for(int i = 0;i < n; i++);
{
    char name[NAME_MAX + 1];
    snprintf(name, NAME_MAX, "test_%d_.txt", i);
    FILE* file = fopen(name,"w");
....
```

В POSIX (*nix) операционных системах обычно существует файл [limits.h](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=limits.h&category=3&russian=4), в котором определено много   констант, характеризующих данную ОС (включая широко известные `INT_MAX`, `INT_MIN` и т.п.).

Среди них -- `NAME_MAX` (максимальный размер имени файла, не включая завершающий `\0`) и `PATH_MAX` (максимальный размер полного пути с именем файла, включающий завершающий `\0`).

Хорошей практикой для написания переносимого (portable) кода будет включать этот файл (`#include <limits.h>`) и использовать определенные там константы.

Еще один вариант динамического создания имен файлов -- использовать функцию [asprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) (в GNU "из коробки", для других систем ее несложно реализовать самому на основе [vsprintf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vsprintf.3.html)).

```
.....
char *name;
asprintf(&name, "test_%d_.txt", i);
// теперь в переменной name указатель на динамически выделенную (по malloc) память,
// содержащую сформированное имя файла
FILE* file = fopen(name,"w");
....
free(name); // освободим память, когда имя больше не нужно 
.....
```

Comment: С вашим кодом вылетает ошибка  error: 'i' undeclared (first use in this function) на строке с snprintf!

Comment: @НАГИБАТОР05, это же не полная программа, а демонстрационный фрагмент кода. Вы уж сами определите в нужных местах вашей программы нужные переменные.

Answer (score 1):

Развивая идеи с размером буфера - можно воспользоваться тем, что при передаче `NULL` в `sprintf` возвращается необходимый размер...

```
const char *fmt = "test_%d.txt";
int sz = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, i);
char buf[sz + 1]; 
snprintf(buf, sz + 1, fmt, i);
FILE* file = fopen(buf,"w");
```